# Location reload in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jasmine

I'm really not sure how to approach testing this? (spyOn?)

```
function reloadPage() {
  $('#logo').click(function() {
    location.reload();
  })
}
```

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you may be unsure about how to test this piece of code is because it's doing 2 different things and you should break it up into smaller chunks.

I see two distinct functions here:

- click event handling
- reload page

So why not break up the logic like so?

```
function reloadPage() {
    location.reload();
}

function bindEvents() {
    $('#logo').click(reloadPage);
}
```

Now you can test them separately using Spies:

```
describe('when the logo is clicked', function() {
   var logo;
   var handlers;
   beforeEach(function() {
       handlers = {
           locationReload: location.reload, // handle for location.reload()
           reloadPage: reloadPage      // handle for your reloadPage()
       };

       logo = $('#logo').click(reloadPage);

       // attach Spy on reloadPage() and let the function call through
       spyOn(handlers, 'reloadPage').and.callThrough();

       // attach Spy on location.reload() 
       spyOn(handlers, 'locationReload');

   });

   it('will execute reloadPage function', function() {
        logo.trigger('click');
        expect(handlers.reloadPage).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });

   it('will reload the page', function() {
        logo.trigger('click');
        expect(handlers.locationReload).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });

   afterEach(function() {
       // clean up event bindings after each test
       logo.off('click');
   });

});
```

There's not much need to test that the `reloadPage` handler was correctly added to the `#logo`'s click event because the test is simulating a `.click()` and checking if `reloadPage` gets called or not.

So most likely you'd only need to have the `it('will reload the page')` spec, not both.

Comment: thanks @sweetamylase! that's great advise on breaking up the one function into two. it does looks like when I run the test, it states "Expected spy reloadPage to have been called." and "Expected spy locationReload to have been called."? do you happen to know why it's doing that?