# Location Reload Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I got a problem with mocking the location reload functionality within Jasmine. I tried several methods ([method 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344058/location-reload-in-jasmine) , [method 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306194/mock-window-location-reload-in-jasmine-testing)) to mock any location reload events but with no luck.

My situation is the following thing. I have a rather simple function:

```
function TestCall(xhr) {
   if (xhr === 401) {       
        location.reload();
   }
}
```

I tried creating the following Jasmine tests:

```
it("FakeCall", function (){
    spyOn(TestCall, 'reload').and.callFake(function(){});
    TestCall(401);
    expect(TestCall).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this should check if reload functionality have been called 
});
```

I want to mock the location reload function but I have no clue why this does not work. Can anyone guide/tell me what I do wrong?

Total code:

```
describe("multiple scripts", function () {
    describe("2# FakeCall", function() {                            
        function TestCall(xhr) {            
            if (xhr === 401) {      
                location.reload();
            }
        }           

        it("2.1 # Reload", function (){                         
            spyOn(location, 'reload');
            TestCall(401);
            expect(location.reload).toHaveBeenCalled();                 
        }); 
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use spyOn, you give object as the first argument and a name of its method (it is attribute of that object) as the second.

So instead of `spyOn(TestCall, 'reload')` use this `spyOn(location, 'reload')`. Now it should work.

In your case it could look like this

```
it("FakeCall", function (){
  spyOn(location, 'reload');
  TestCall(401);
  expect(location.reload).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation but how would that  work within my example? Because I test it and the response I get is: `Expected a spy, but got file`

Comment: Do you than verify it like `expect(location.reload).toHaveBeenCalled();` ?

Comment: No, I did now but if I do that I get the following message: `Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.` Btw thanks for your help ;)

Comment: You mean even if you try the piece of code I just added to my answer, it still doesn't work? Works for me in Jasmine + Karma in PhantomJS and Chrome.

Comment: Yep, Look at my edited questions. I added the total test. I use Jasmine-standalone runner btw but that should not matter right? Could  you check if my setting is the same as yours?

Comment: I've run your code and it works. But you can try to use `window.location` instead of `location`. Additionally, I suggest you try [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html) for your client-side code tests, as it gives you many benefits including possibility to test your code in multiple real browsers at once.

Comment: For some reasons when I run it in PhantomJS directly via command line it does not break and the test succeeds. Fair enough. Still strange why it should not work within my chrome browser. One last question. Do you use a specific jQuery version?

Comment: I've tried but I just don't get your Error in Chrome, strange. I avoid jQuery wherever possible, so I don't use it at all.